# Diagonalizing a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a symmetric matrix with real coefficients. Then I know that $A$ is diagonalizable. Does the following hold? 
Suppose $P^{-1}AP = D$ where $D$ is diagonal.   Does it then follow that $P$ is an orthogonal matrix? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does not.  In particular, note that if $P^{-1}AP = D$, then we also have $(2P)^{-1}A(2P) = D$.  It is impossible for $P$ and $2P$ to both be orthogonal.

Comment: It's not even necessary that the columns of $P$ be orthogonal to each other.  That is, even if $P$ has unit length columns, $P$ might not be an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: @Brian right, but that can only occur if $A$ has a repeated eigenvalue